# Angular : Best way to check queries parameters for all routes

Tags: angular

I would like to check all queries parameters for all route. 
I dont want to use the guard because the checking may be long.
I would like to check after navigation for example in AfterViewInit.
What is the best way to check all queries parameters for all route ?

Regards

Comment: your question is unclear. what do you mean by "check all query parameters" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#activatedroute):

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

In the lifecycle hook:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
 console.log(params);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject Router and log it's config prop. But its gonna work only for preloaded (not ladyloaded) modules, i.e.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log(router.config)
  }
}
```